# Can we have an additional flag to indicate technical inaccuracies?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, wrong-answers

I just got:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

For flagging the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203615/395659), using the <*not an answer*> flag, which is ok, but I think it could be helpful to have a flag for such a case, something like "*Misleading*" or "*Technically incorrect*", because such an answer with **105 upvotes** would definitely mislead visitors and it does not answer the question or part of it.

Is there anything one can do in this case to bring moderator attention other than flagging the post? downvoting doesn't really help here with 105 upvotes.

Comment: Attention other than flagging a post is reporting on meta site, which you did properly. Now moderator will take care of it.

Comment: Just a quick update; I've gone ahead and deleted it. See my answer/comments below for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Down voting is the *only* thing you can do. Moderators are not here to judge the correctness or lack thereof of answers; the community does that through votes.

That said, there does seem to be something 'off' with that answer; my limited knowledge of the subject seems to suggest it really is not an answer to the question asked. But I don't have enough knowledge here to say for certain, so I'll have to defer to someone who knows better.

Incidentally; it is *extremely rare* that domain knowledge is required to identify a "Not an Answer" post, because it's usually obvious. This one could be be an exception.

NOTE: Nothing I'm saying here guarantees that answer will be deleted; I *think* it qualifies as NAA because it does not attempt to answer the question, but I don't think it enough to tell you outright it was a mistake to decline that flag. The post could still just be a 'very wrong' post, and the votes for it an anomaly. I'm actually poking around at the post some, too; as that could be a strange number of votes for something like that.

Comment: It certainly doesn't seem to answer the *actual* question, but it seems to fit the question's *title*, which is probably why many (well, 10 000 people) have seen it and thought it helpful. Possibly.

Comment: @J.Steen Yup; that's what I was thinking. My brain is starting to be fried from the late night, so I just wanted to be careful ;)

Comment: Thank you, i am not worried about the declined flag, but i knwo that SO became a success because of certain quality which makes it serious once, and the fact that in such a case (which is pretty rare) the community and moderatros can not do anything is somehow wierd and affects the site reputation.

Comment: @OneMore Keep in mind I am just being careful due to my unfamiliarity with the language and the 100+ up votes. Also, when the moderator who handled it saw that flag in the queue, they probably saw the *title* of the question, and saw that the answer *did* appear to answer it. So it was likely just a simple mistake to decline it. This works out fine 99.999% of the time, and we'll handle it properly this time, too. It was just an outlier due to a combination of tiny factors.

Comment: @J.Steen People who see the post doesnt certainly mean because of the answer, the question may be a usual problem but the answer to use VerticalAlignmentCenter is pretty wrong to a question on how to between center and bottom allignment

Comment: @OneMore Yes, we do agree, no need to explain further. We were just exploring *why*. =)

Comment: @OneMore I've gone ahead and deleted it. We agree with you about the nature of that answer; it wasn't a *wrong* answer - it actually was not an answer to the question asked at all. It just *appeared* to be an answer at first glance. We handle *lots* of flags on Stack Overflow, and sometimes we miss little things.

Comment: Thank you , good luck guys.

Comment: Downvotes *and comments explaining the inaccuracy*!

Answer (score 7):

Moderators are janitors not experts on everything and all.

Wrong answers are what downvotes are for, not flags.